# Git authentication issue - "GitHub does not provide shell access."

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-authentication

I'm following this video https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-identifying-how-to-contribute-to-an-open-source-project-on-github to setup my local machine and Github.

I have successfully added the ssh authentication key to my Github account, but when I check, the below will appear.

`$ ssh -T git@github.com`

`Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/dilkh/.ssh/id_rsa':`

`Hi Dilkhan-1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

I'm confused. I'm trying to link my local machine and github so they can communicate as said in the tutorial. I'm trying to setup my Git for Github contributions. When I tried the "ssh -T git@github.com" This says, "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access." What could the problem be? Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: A cursory glance at that video makes me think it's a very poor resource.  Github itself produces adequate documentation - read https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal. The docs about [testing ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) say you will get that response when it's successful.

You should be able to clone repos via SSH now.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm able to clone fine.